# tfsBuildExtensions Assemblyinfo activity in tfs 2013 implementation issues

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, assemblyinfo

I am using the default template (tfvsTemplate.12.xaml) to customize my build.
I want to auto increment the AssemblyVersion build number in our nightly deployment builds.
I set it up as recommended here:
 https://github.com/tfsbuildextensions/CustomActivities/wiki/Getting%20started%20with%20the%20AssemblyInfo%20activity

except for one step.
in my template, I was unable to find the "Get Workspace" activity, so I put my sequence a after the
"Get sources from Team Foundation Version Control" --> "Associate the changesets that occurred since the last good build" activities.
I have the "find matching files" activity looking in the WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.SourcesDirectory.
the build runs correctly, and the log shows that it found the correct file, however the assembly version number and the assembly file number are not incrementing (both are set to "$(current).$(current).$(current).$(increment)").
one thought I had is that the file may be read only, and may need that changed to work correctly.
I installed the dlls from the codeplex download into tfs, it is able to use them without issue.

Can someone please review and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you
debbie

Comment: You are trying to use the old way with the new template ... Done that myself a bunch. Switch to PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

You should remove all of your customisations and go back to the default template. Then download the equivalent PowerShell and use that.

https://github.com/tfsbuildextensions/CustomActivities/blob/master/Source/Scripts/ApplyVersionToAssemblies.ps1

You can then add the PowerShell to the Pre-Build script location.